# Make git branch --list always imply --all

Tags: git

I have to work with branches quite often. I don't always have a tracking branch and even if I do, they are not always up to date. Because of that I just spent a couple of minutes finding a commit because I forgot to add `--all` to a `git branch --contains <sha1>`.

It would be very useful if listing could just imply `--all` (regardless whether `--list` is actually written or implied). I haven't found a config setting but maybe I didn't look for the right terms. Is it possible to have `git branch` behave that way?

Comment: Why not simply define an alias for `git branch --all`?

Comment: @Jubobs I'd like to avoid that if possible (doesn't seem likely now). I'm just not a big fan of aliases.

Comment: And I'm not a big fan of modifying Git's default behavior myself :)

Comment: @Jubobs `git config` has a staggering number of configuration options that allow you to tailor git's behavior to your needs without resolving to aliases. I have nothing against aliases per se, it's just personal preference.

Comment: At the time of writing, Git (2.4.5) doesn't offer such a configuration option. Therefore, you'd be better off defining an alias for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a git alias:

```
git config --global alias.br 'branch --all'
```